# Opening a fancyBox with a certain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Does anyone know how I can open a resizable fancyBox with a certain aspect ratio (for example 16:9)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the specified ratio to be automatically maintained as the user resizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a pure CSS solution too. It works even when you resize.

```
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner{
    padding-top: 56.2%; /* (9/16 * 100%) -- your aspect ratio in percents */
    height: 0 !important;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner .fancybox-iframe{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm assuming you needed this for a video displayed with fancybox. Hence the iframe-related css.

P.S. I know this thread is old. But maybe someone still needs a solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Fancybox 3, the class names are different. If you're using version, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a native way of easily resizing Fancybox. You can do some simple math with **screen.height** to open a Fancybox in a particular aspect ratio relative to the current screen resolution.

```
var height = screen.height/4;

$("#test").fancybox({
           'width' : 16/9. * height,
           'height' : height,
           'autoDimensions' : false
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure css solution for responsive youtube popups that works with Fancybox 3. It's written in scss for clearness but can be converted to css online if you're not familiar with scss.

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe {

    .fancybox-content{
        margin: 0!important;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 56.2%; /* (9/16 * 100%) -- your aspect ratio in percents */
        height: 0 !important;

        /* don't go full width on wide screens */
        @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
            max-width: 70%;
            width: 70%;
            padding-top: 39.34%;  /* (9/16 * 70%) -- smaller aspect ratio in percents */
        }

        .fancybox-iframe{ 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 0; 
            right: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Fancybox right now, does not support this. However, You can control the dimension of fancy box size

```
("#yourbox").fancybox({
    'width'             : 680,
    'height'             495,
    'showCloseButton'   : false,
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'titleFormat'       : formatTitle
});
```